# Is my server lacking storage space?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, windows, timeout

I have two ASP.Net web applications using SQL Server 2005 hosted on a dedicated  Windows 2003 server. One of the applications only receives around 100 unique hits a day, however, the other receives on average 6,000 unique hits a day. Both applications have been live for around 4 years now without any problems.

Recently I have noticed both applications slowing down quite a bit, page loads taking a long time, much longer than usual. I have also noticed one of the applications getting the following error maybe once or twice a day

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout
>   period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
>   not responding.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)

The capacity of the two databases together comes to around 3 Gig, and the C Drive on the Server is around 20 Gig. However, the current free space on the C Drive is sitting at 3 Gig.

I thought originally the timeout error was coming from leaking connections in my code, but now I am not so sure because as stated, the applications have been live for 4 years now without any trouble like this.

Do you think the issue could be my server?

Comment: Unlikely to be storage, however your database tables and indices may be severely fragmented and slow/inefficient - how large are the tables in use?  Also, is any part of the file system used as storage besides for the database (for images or such)?

Comment: May also be worthwhile to look at how big your logs are. A common problem is the `modellog.ldf` file getting huge (among other logs). Check `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data` for any logs that may be overwhelmingly large.

Comment: PinnyM The majority of the tables in each database will contain around 50,000 records, however, there are some other tables which are used just as much, and have around 900,000 records stored in them.

Comment: You seem to keep asking a similar question.. Are your tables all indexed? Are your queries running optimally? As the above commenter suggests - you should look at these areas..

Comment: @Steve I have taken on board the suggestions from my previous questions which may look similar to you, ie, all my tables are now indexed, however, I am still experiencing difficulties, hence, I am asking new questions? I do hope that is ok by you?

Comment: This wasnt a criticism, just an observation that you still seem to be having this particular problem.. If you post the actual SQL you're trying to run, maybe someone can help as it may well be this that is the problem.

Comment: Well, find out what your query is doing: Look at the execution plan and see where the big costs are.